# How to get around sql-server's partition maximum?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

My team is trying to run a script that is in source control to create partitions and we're running into the following error: `CREATE/ALTER partition function failed as only a maximum of 1000 partitions can be created.`

Part of script:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PFDailyPartition](DATETIME)
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('01/01/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/02/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/03/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/04/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/05/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/06/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/07/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/08/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/09/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/10/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/11/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/12/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/13/2005 00:00:00'
 '01/14/2005 00:00:00'
 etc...
```

Running `select * from sys.partition_range_values` on our current setup shows that we have over 10,000 partitions.

Is there any way to get around this 1000 limit?  We can't figure out how we have this many partitions already.

Could it be an environmental difference between the two setups?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your partition function is creating separate partitions by day.  That's a lot of partitions!  Since 2005, this would be roughly 365 * 7 = 2,555 partitions.  Do you realy want separate partitions by day?

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg981694.aspx), SQL Server 2008 SP2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 increased the limit to 15,000 partitions.  Is there a service pack difference between the servers?

Quoted from the article:

> **Problem**
>
> SQL Server 2005 introduced table and index partitioning. Partitioning
>   can make large tables and indexes more manageable and scalable. For
>   more information about partitioning, see Partitioned Tables and
>   Indexes
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188706(v=SQL.100).aspx). In
>   SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2008 R2, the number
>   of partitions is limited to 1,000.
>
> Customers primarily use partitioning to facilitate the management of
>   large fact tables in data warehouses. Data warehouse customers
>   commonly load data as a batch. Daily loads are the most common
>   pattern, but increasingly customers want to load data more than once a
>   day. With the limit of 1,000 partitions, if customers load daily, they
>   can store less than three years of data in a partitioned table,
>   whereas business requirements often mandate that data be retained for
>   longer periods of time, such as seven years. The 1,000 partitions
>   maximum becomes a limitation for customers in this scenario.
>
> If merging of partitions is too complex and time-consuming, customers
>   prefer to have the flexibility to create a large number of partitions
>   and use them as and when required. The 1,000 partitions maximum also
>   becomes a limitation in this scenario.
>
> **Solution**
>
> In SQL Server 2008 SP2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, **you can choose to
>   enable support for 15,000 partitions at a database-level granularity
>   by using the new sp_db_increased_partitions stored procedure**. You can
>   also disable support on a database (after it has been enabled) and set
>   the limit on the number of partitions back to 1,000.